# css triple border?

Tags: css, responsive-design, border

Hello i'm trying to create a triple border using css. Right now what I've got is two borders but the second border doesn't go around the element(`div.container#main`) completely.

I've been following this [blog post](http://jaspreetchahal.org/pure-css-double-and-triple-borders/). [JSFiddle](http://goo.gl/3R4Qd).

Any help on getting the border to go around the element completely would be great.

Comment: @prodigitalson The `div.container#main` element.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/J3e9R/1/

Comment: @prodigitalson Yes that's perfect

Comment: k... added step by step explanation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So essentially the problem is youre using position aboslute and calculating things from the worng elements.

When something is absolutely positioned in only gains height when that height is specified or when the element has content. A workaround for that in this case is to assign both a `top` and `bottom` value, which will essentially make the element exapand. You forgot the `bottom` value. Adding it gives us this:

http://jsfiddle.net/J3e9R/2/

However youll notice now the element goes to the bottom of the view port. This is because without a positioned parent (relative, absolute, static) it defaults to the top level element as the context for positioning.

To get around this we can either add an extra wrapper element and give it position relative, or we can move our border styles onto your `div.row`; Either way the technique is the same, just depends on whether you can add a another wrapper or whether the `div.row` will work for your situation. So that gives this:

http://jsfiddle.net/J3e9R/3/

Now you can see we actually have the inner border working in concert with the dimensions of the box. But now our position is off. This is because instead of calculating our offset from the outer element `#main` we are working from the inside out so we need to invert our measurements:

http://jsfiddle.net/J3e9R/4/

Ok, now we are back to having the order on the outer edge of our original box, so we just need to bring it in to the middle of our outer border, so we jsut change the measurement to about half, finally giving us what we want:

http://jsfiddle.net/J3e9R/1/

Comment: Perfect exactly what I was looking for. Also great explanation.